# Question on force invariance under the Galilean Transformations (GT)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

By the Galilean transformations, one can easily derive that two different inertial observers 1,2 always measure the same forces. That is:

$$ \textbf{F}_1 \ \left(\textbf{r}_1, \dot{\textbf{r}}_1,t_1\right) = \textbf{F}_2 \ \left(\textbf{r}, \dot{\textbf{r}}_2,t_2\right) \ \ \ \ (1)$$

with $\textbf{r}_1$ and $\textbf{r}_2 $ satisfying:

$$ \textbf{r}_1 = \textbf{r}_0 + t \textbf{v}_0 \ + \textbf{r}_2 \ \ \forall \ t\in \mathbb R$$

and $ t_1 $ and $ t_2 $:
$$ t_1 = t_2 + a $$
(All the constants have the usual meaning)

Are there any force fields that violate (1)? and how can one prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Electromagnetic forces are not invariant under Galilean transformations. (Because they transform instead under Lorentz transformations.)

For a simple example, consider two point charges $q$ travelling side by side at speed $v$ in the same direction, distance $d$ apart. The attractive magnetic force between them is

$$F=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\frac{q^2v^2}{d^2}.$$

Now do a Galilean transformation into a frame moving along with the two particles. Their speed is now zero so in this frame the magnetic force is

$$F’=0.$$